# Vallidation errors with saveAll in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have a list of User records that I'm saving at one time (the form is populated from an uploaded CSV).

Everything seems to be working fine, and my validation rules are being honoured, but one thing that's eluding me are the specific validation error messages.

I get the general validation error (if say, a field that is supposed to be unique is not), but I'm not getting an error on the specific field to let the user know what the actual problem is.

Is this a bug, or is there something wrong with my Code? Here's the action from my Controller (fwiw I'm passing the CSV data to this action from another action, hence the snippet at the beginning):

```
public function finalizeCsv() {
    if ( isset($this->request->params['named']['csvData']) ) {
        $csvData = unserialize( $this->request->params['named']['csvData'] );
    } else {
        $csvData = $this->request->data;
    }
    $this->set('users', $csvData);
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $csvData;
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Users added!', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('There were errors with your data.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing the saveAll() to `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)`

Comment: Because of how my data's coming in, I have to pluck the array from within it. I can refactor but would this really make a difference? Everything is saving and validating properly, I'm just not getting the specific errors.

Comment: Refactored, no change. My entire save is invalidated, so I know my validation rules are being honoured, but specific errors are not appearing on offending fields.

Comment: So `$this->request->data['User']` has the form field data?  And in the view you use `$this->Form->create('User')` ?

Comment: Not any more. Edited question.

Answer (score 1):

For unique fields add a validation rule

```
'field_name' => array(
    'rule' => 'isUnique',
    'required' => 'create'
),
```

Next - when you get a error you will need to review `$this->User->validationErrors`. There will be many arrays inside - 1 for each created record. Loop through them, collect errors and send them to $this->Session->setFlash().
Also you better wrap `$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)` into transaction if you're using InnoDB or other engine that supports transactions. On error - do rollback and try again.

```
$ds = $this->User->getDataSource();
$ds->begin();
// > saving here < //
$ds->commit(); //< on success
$ds->rollback(); //< on error
```

Comment: The InnoDB is a great tip. I'm not sure if you really read the question though. 1) I have validation rules that are function just fine. 2) I'm able to return the general Auth flash. 3) The problem is that field-specific errors are not appearing, as they do when only saving a single record.

Comment: You haven't listed your validation rules, so I assumed you might have missed ('rule' => 'isUnique'). Ok. Let's do diag =) 1) you have a rule 'isUnique' for a field 2) you don't have a Php error or DB error while saving duplicate item; 3) you get false from saveAll(); 4) $this->User->validationErrors are empty (note that array format differs from the one save() method produces); 5) you already managed to save at least 1 pack of users and it was successful. 6) debug mode is on.

Comment: If all above is true - then you'd better use foreach() and User->create(); User->save($oneRecord). They at least work as expected =)

Comment: I wondered if it would come to that... I was hoping to keep it as automagical as possible. :)

Comment: Acually Cake's magic sometimes fail like hell. Currently I'm tryng to avoid the most black magic =)

Comment: If you have time - you can go to Cake's source code and try to find a problem. Or try to update Cake to latest version if you use old one